# Why does Green Arrow hate Batman?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, green-arrow

In the 'Under the Hood' arc, in Batman #639, Batman goes to Star City to ask Green Arrow about his resurrection.

Green Arrow displays hostility. After their conversation, Batman says something like:

> Why do you hate me? I know it couldn't be something I did to you. You're not that shallow. So it must be something you did to me.

After that, Batman leaves. As he's leaving, Arrow hangs his head and says "I'm sorry", presumably to himself as he remembers what Batman was referring to.

Could anyone tell me which incident is being referred to here? And which issue(s) did it take place in?

[image]

<sub>Image from imgur.com. Copyright: DC Comics</sub>

Comment: Those frames suggest to me that the hostility stemmed from guilt rather than hatred..

Comment: Ollie has always hated Bruce because they are on opposite sides of the political spectrum. Basically Ollie is an SJW and Batman is everything wrong with the world. As far as what Ollie did specifically to Batman I can think of nothing off the top of my head. There was nothing in Batman comics that I can think of that they could be referring to that I remember. So it's either the normal hatred or something that happened in Green Arrow Comics (which I never followed.)

Comment: Not in the picture above. Batman mentions 'anger' but I don't see 'hatred' anywhere in it..

Comment: @AndrewThompson: He says it in the previous page, like I mentioned in my comment. I'll see if I can find a picture.

Comment: The page or two before can be found at http://panels-of-interest.tumblr.com/post/135310543685/batman-vs-green-arrow-from-batman-1940-639

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Umm.. OK. Read all the text content & still don't see the word 'hate'. What am I missing? Could you quote the exact text that includes it?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Sorry. I should have clarified that the pages I linked above also do not contain the word "hate" or "hatred". :) Just including them for reference. I personally think that they do help provide context, but it's a lot of pages to put all in one query.

Answer (score 7):

The [general consensus](http://www.comicbloc.com/forums/archive/index.php?t-3445.html) so far by people on the internet seems to be that it's about the [Identity Crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_Crisis_(DC_Comics)), when Ollie and several others had Batman's memory erased.

> Wally West questions Green Arrow again after accidentally seeing a snapshot of the battle on the Satellite in Light's mind, which reveals that Batman was also present. Green Arrow confesses that Batman had left immediately after the battle, but soon unexpectedly returned just as the mind wipe was taking place. He disapproved this and nearly attacked the other heroes; he was magically restrained and his memory of the incident was removed.

Comment: I've found a few different pages where people speculate that it's about Identity Crisis, but no proof, and at least one page where the theory is discounted because this is already-known information.

Comment: It's possble considering the 2 stories overlap at that point in time. That would be my best guess considering Batman (and the batfamily) and Green Arrow hardly ever interact and that seems like the most likely thing they're talking about. The only other major thing to happen around the same time frame is the Death of Stephanie Brown and could refer an indirect connection between her and GA through The Birds of Prey, which could be argued ultimately led to her death. GA is the type of char that would make those connections and act like that over them so within the realm of possibility.

Comment: I think you're on to something. But considering Batman discovered that his memory was erased and created the Brother MK I, I thought it wasn't about that. Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't 'Under the Hood' set after/concurrently with 'OMAC Project'? My point being: if Batman meets Arrow while OMAC stuff is going on, or even immediately before that, it would still mean he has had Brother MK I up for a while, which would mean he knew about the Zatanna memory-wipe thing already.

Answer (score 7):

Green Arrow and Batman always have had that sense of tension, years before the retro story in "Identity Crisis." Some of it is philosophical.

Green Arrow is less reactionary than the other members of The Justice League. Green Arrow is not above using lethal force to take out villains such as Prometheus. He also has shown trying to deal with higher-level social concepts, such as racism and drug wars. He sees The Justice League as being able to do more on the street with their superpowers and abilities.

Batman, on the other hand, is an authoritative figure when it comes to dictating to other superheroes. Batman sets rules for other members of The Justice League and another set of rules for himself (like leaving and not joining in missions when he feels like it). Green Arrow is much more of a free-flowing person who chafes under such restrictions, and is one of the few Justice League members who stands up to Batman's selective dogma.

In some ways, Green Arrow sees Batman as self-serving and hypocritical -- he knows how life is for people in crime-infected areas yet does nothing to stop corruption until it reaches a certain stage. For instance, Green Arrow is someone who would try to kill The Joker, especially given how much pain The Joker inflicted on Gotham City and Batman personally. Yet Batman continually repeats locking up The Joker in Arkham Asylum and waits until he escapes again.

Additionally, some of that contempt is based on how similar they are to each other. Batman and Green Arrow are street-level superheroes who use their skills and resources to fight crime and address villains the more powerful heroes rarely address. Both men are stubborn with complicated relationships with their respective inner circles.

However, when it comes to certain situations Batman shows he will trust Green Arrow. They seem to have a begrudgingly mutual respect. In that context, they are an example of two people who don't get along because they see too much of themselves in the other person.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely *Identity Crisis*. In a later story arc of JLA (starting in #115) Batman teams up with GA and others from the mind wipe incident and he and GA hash it out a bit more. I don't think it's resolved in the story. The only person I know Batman actually resolves his anger towards regarding the incident is Zatanna. He saves her life in a Detective Comics story line she appears in and they talk about it and settle things as friends.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a bit more?

Comment: Good answer. I'm with @Gallifreyan. I'd really like to know the issues of Detective Comics you're referring to.

Answer (score 2):

It definitely refers to Identity Crisis. Batman understood that for the safety of them and their loved ones, sometimes the JLA had to resort to wiping someone's memory of their identity to keep things safe. He was FINE with Zatanna wiping Dr. Light's memory of Elongated Man's wife (he'd broken into the Watchtower to steal back something they'd taken from him and found her, and decided to get back at the JLA by raping her. They got her distress call too late and arrested him but he promised he'd come after her again. While Batman was gone they decided that the only way to keep Dr. Light from offending again was not just to take his memory but alter his personality to make him less dangerous.

Batman walked in while they were doing this and tried to stop them, so Zatanna wiped his memory of it so he wouldn't know what they'd done to Light. However, with Bruce being Batman, Oliver knew that sooner or later Batman would realize something had happened, and would know that Oliver knew that he knew. I believe that's what's being referenced. Ollie his hostile towards Bruce because he feels guilty for letting it happen when he was against it, and Bruce knows that.

Comment: This is a great answer, but could you maybe provide a link to an edition or a few editions where all this has happened? That would really help support your answer.